# ASP .NET page request size

Tags: asp.net, size, request

I have a ASP .Net web-application running on IIS 7/Win2K8 Standard.

What I would like help with :

As a user makes a request on the client side (browser), I want to examine the request object on the server as soon as it arrives (for logging purposes).

In particular I want to log, at the very least :

1. Time of the request.
2. IP address of the request.
3. Size in bytes of the request.

Similarly I want to log the size of the response being rendered for the same request.

The request may be an entire page request or a partial update (updatepanel) request.

Much obliged for any help provided.

Thanks in anticipation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Handle the Application_BeginRequest event in your Global.asax file.  Something like this:

```
public void Application_BeginRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e) {
     yourLogger.Log(String.Format("Request Time: {0}, Request IP: {1}, Request Size: {2}",
                                  Date.Now.Time,
                                  Request.UserHostAddress,
                                  Request.TotalBytes)
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, just.another.programmer.

Sometimes, when in a block, just being able to start somewhere seems like a huge task accomplished.

Answer (score 1):

Well beside the answer from @just.another.programmer, I would like to recommend another approach

If you want to be completely sure that each request and response will actually be logged **even if an unhandled exception ocurrs**, then you should consider using the: [LogRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpapplication.logrequest.aspx) event or the [PostLogRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpapplication.postlogrequest.aspx)

From MSDN

> Occurs just before ASP.NET performs any logging for the current request.
>
> The LogRequest event is raised even if an error occurs. You can provide an event handler for the LogRequest event to provide custom logging for the request.

In order to use this event, your application must be running in Integrated mode in IIS 7.0 and with the .NET Framework 3.0 or later.

These events occur at the end of the Request life-cycle:

References:

- [Application Life-cycle in IIS 5 and 6](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178473.aspx)
- [Application Life-cycle in IIS 7](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb470252.aspx)